# Is there any way to run a php file with php.exe and a friendly gui?

Tags: php, linux, windows, parameters, exe

I run my php script in windows console, with CMD and writing:

```
[PATH to php.ext]\php.exe [path_to_file]\file.php parameter
```

Is there any way to run a php file with a GUI (or similar) and input text for ask a parameter without using the browser?. Something like this:

[image]

---

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Basic Script is a valid option for me:

```
sub shell(cmd)    

' Run a command as if you were running from the command line

dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run(cmd)
Set objShell = Nothing
end sub

dim name

' Ask the user for a parameter

name = inputbox("Parameter", "Title", "")

if name <> "" then

' The user gave the parameter.  Open the program
' with the value the user gave.

shell "php.exe file.php " & name
else
msgbox "User cancelled.", 16, "User cancelled"
end if
```